Teradata summary query
Sample input



stl_dt
stst_cd




2024-07-25
12


2024-07-28
12


2024-07-28
14



Expected output:



Type
Total




A1
2


A2
3


A3
1



If stst_cd is 12 then A1 is 1
If stl_dt<current_date then A2 is 1
If stst_cd is 14 then A3 is 1
Please help with the teradata query to capture the value in both types.

These sound like pretty basic case statements, what have you tried?

Your example appears to be a pivoted count. Perhaps a larger example would clarify.

Case When  stst_cd=12 then A1 when stl_dt<current_date then A2 end as type

A simple aggregate query would give you totals as a row:
SELECT 
    SUM(CASE WHEN stst_cd = 12 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS A1,
    SUM(CASE WHEN stl_dt < CURRENT_DATE THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS A2,
    SUM(CASE WHEN stst_cd = 14 then 1 ELSE 0 END) AS A3
    FROM mytable;




A1
A2
A3




2
3
1



Not sure there is much value having the result be rows instead of columns, but that could be done by applying UNPIVOT to the above:
WITH conditions AS (SELECT 
    SUM(CASE WHEN stst_cd = 12 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS A1,
    SUM(CASE WHEN stl_dt < CURRENT_DATE THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS A2,
    SUM(CASE WHEN stst_cd = 14 then 1 ELSE 0 END) AS A3
    FROM mytable)
SELECT * 
    FROM conditions
    UNPIVOT(Total FOR "Type" IN (A1,A2,A3)) T
-- Type is a keyword, so to use as a column name it should be quoted
;

